# Self-executing function in object initialiser can't see object's properties

Tags: javascript

I know about function scope, self-executing functions, hoisting and other cool words, but I am totally of-base with the following.

```
var o = {
    a : 1,
    f : (function(){
      console.log(this.a);
    })()
};
```

Why is this gives me `undefined`? Function is self-executed right when the object is initialized, therefore I expect it to already assign a to 1. But it is not doing this.

Comment: Well. This.a refers to a from function and not o.

Comment: I highly doubt the fiddle is needed. You can just copy it in the console.

Comment: @JoakimM plz write this as an answer. Also do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Self-executed function is invoked in global object context. this refers to window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're not calling it via `o`, its `this` is not `o`.

Additionally you never assing the function to anything either - `f` is set to be the return value (`undefined`).

Answer (score 3):

The function is not called in the scope of your newly created object, but in the global scope. There, `a` (or `window.a`) is indeed `undefined`. The braces themselves do not create a new block. Only when you call a method later, `this` is bound to `o` as you assume. Compare it with this:

```
var o = {
    a : 1,
    f : function(){
      console.log(this.a);
    }
};
o.f(); // console prints 1
```